# Ordenar tupla (a,a,a)

Tags: haskell, programación-funcional

Hola buenas tengo la siguiente tupla:

```
ordena :: Ord a => (a,a,a) -> (a,a,a)
```

a ver esto no tiene mucha complicación pero como lo hago yo sale un codigo muy feo y largo.

En este caso pregunto a ver si hay algun tipo de recursividad que pueda hacer para ordenarlo de menor a mayor

Comment: ¿Se trata también de uno de esos problemas que no se puede usar ningún módulo estándar? Si al menos pusieras el código que has probado, podríamos hacernos una idea más concreta de si se puede hacer igual, pero más elegante.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sin usar ningún módulo (como supongo que se desea), una solución directa y simple sería:

```
ordena :: Ord a => (a,a,a) -> (a,a,a)
ordena (x,y,z) | x > y     = ordena (y,x,z)
               | y > z     = ordena (x,z,y)
               | otherwise = (x,y,z)
```

Comment: Si, muchas gracias, perdona que conteste tan tarde, yo lo había puesto caso por caso por lo que salen 18000 guardas.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes convertir la tupla en una lista, ordenar la lista, y devolver la tupla:

```
import Data.List(sort)
ordena :: Ord a => (a,a,a) -> (a,a,a)
ordena (a,b,c) = let [d,e,f] = sort [a,b,c] in (d,e,f)
```